# Would a Zealot barbarian's Divine Fury feature trigger during an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, opportunity-attack, barbarian

The [Path of the Zealot barbarian](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot) (*Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, p. 11) gets the [Divine Fury](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#DivineFury-644) feature at level 3, which states:

> At 3rd level, while you're raging, the first creature you hit on each of your turns with a weapon attack takes extra damage equal to 1d6 + half your barbarian level. The extra damage is necrotic or radiant; you choose the type of damage when you gain this feature.

Does it work like the Rogue's Sneak Attack, in that it can trigger on opportunity attacks, since it's a different turn? Or does the "on each of your turns" bit make it not work for opportunity attacks, since they generally don't occur on your turn?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Divine Fury can only apply to attacks made on *your* turn.

[Divine Fury](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/barbarian#PathoftheZealot) says:

> While you’re raging, the first creature you hit on each of **your turns** with a weapon attack takes extra damage equal to 1d6 + half your barbarian level.

“Each of **your** turns” indicates that it only triggers on your turn. If the opportunity attack was triggered on your turn, you could use Divine Fury if it was the first hit of your turn.

Comment: By contrast, the Sneak Attack phrasing is "Once per turn".  If Divine Fury meant the first of your attacks on *any* turn, it would say "the first time on **a** turn", not *your*.